Shoe deforms in pose mode
My character's shoe deforms when trying to pose my character. The sole of the shoe comes through the shoes and the top of the shoe deforms also. Any advice on how to correct this? Thanks
File: https://we.tl/t-rakRYa6y8a



the reason for this is, that you have a "double shoe" here, as you can see in the gif.
The outer shoe has been weight painted ok.
I hid the vertices of the outer show and showed the the weight painting of the inner show, which looks different, as you can see.
So either you delete the "inner shoe" or weight paint it the same as the outer shoe.
i uploaded the gif to github, because uploading gif here returns an error right now: https://github.com/luckychris/blender_gifs/blob/main/double%20shoe.gif

Perfect answer! Thank you.

you are welcome
